# What should I think about users with huge numbers of successful login attempts in a short period?

Tags: encryption, authentication, exploit, attacks

What to think about a user making thousands of successful login attempts over a short period? What are the dangers of such a behavior and how to protect against them?

A couple of examples of dangers that jump in my mind:

- it might be a DDOS attempt, trying to do a large number of costly operations in a short period of time and creating a large quantity of useless logs.
- each session token obtained ( in the case where the login generates JWT tokens ) may give information about the secret used to compute the signature, allowing maybe the hacker to create JWT tokens for any account/role.

Comment: I doubt either of those is the case.  Unless you are talking about thousands of logins in the space of a second, you're probably no where near DoS levels.  Also, modern hashing/encryption methods are effectively immune to attempts to discover the key from hashed strings.

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer expect by asking the user or watching their actual behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that your user is using a script to connect to your system ? Then maybe he made a mistake that do the connection multiple times

Comment: "... and how to protect against them" : I am assuming this is for a web site? You could implement recaptcha (or similar) which can protect your site against automated login attempts/scripts.

Comment: My first thought would be that it's a user that is doing some sort of automated process at your site, e.g. spidering, screen scraping, or the like.

Comment: @Deunis: in my case, different users had the same pattern; they made thousands of  successful logins in the hours following their registration. They didn't login again after that. The exact number of login varies from these users; some did 20000 logins, some only 200. The pattern being similar, I suspect the same person to be behind these accounts. The email domains of 75% of these accounts seems to be related to the same university.

Comment: @ConorMancone Never underestimate stupidity =). I've seen customers where a simple dirbuster run took the site down due to too many open file handles. Or running nmap took down some important system. I can see how running a few thousand logins can be a DoS test, even if it wasn't in the space of a second.

Answer (score 2):

On the security side, **you can protect yourself** with:

1. Rate limiting tools like fail2ban to block DDoS and other automated noise
2. Recaptcha to block brute force attempts
3. A stateful firewall, intrusion detection, or intrusion prevent appliance to block known attack methods

(This site forbids product recommendations, but there are packaged/supported paid products for each of those categories as well as open source options depending on your preferences.)

**We can't tell you what to think beyond those basics** because this type of question is dependent on data that you may not want to disclose on a public forum. Specifically:

1. A successful login means the client has valid credentials. You'll have to investigate the behavior or contact the user to determine whether the activity was legitimate. Investigation would include a careful review of the relevant logs. *You would need to reset/revoke credentials if the activity is unauthorized.*
2. Automated processes can easily perform hundreds, thousands, or millions of unique actions per second. This could be the result of: (a) an unauthorized tool, (b) an authorized tool working properly, (c) an authorized tool that is misbehaving for some reason; we have no way to know or investigate, or (d) an authorized tool that is being misused. *You would need to whitelist the behavior, reconfigure the tool, revoke access, or block access depending on what is happening.*
3. Do the authentication attempts look like attacks on JWT or not? *You would need to block a bad actor. Preferably, an IPS would handle it automatically, but you could add rules to fail2ban or a firewall as needed.*

If you are a security analyst, you should have the tools to investigate this; if not, then the organization has a deficit that management needs to be aware of. If you are not a security analyst and your company does not have one, there are security consultants that can help investigate.

Comment: Google ReCaptcha is both spyware and [ineffective](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/buster-captcha-solver/). Using something used by fewer websites is much more effective. Rate-limiting per IP (perhaps per subnet: /24 for IPv4, /56 for IPv6) is the most reliable way to limit attackers without annoying users, spying on users, and still letting bots pass with like 90% success rates on most captchas.

Answer (score 1):

I may do this in a security audit if something smells fishy, and I have done so for both reasons you mentioned:

- Denial of Service: I've seen systems that, after too many requests, just bugged out by having too many file handles open. I guess a session system would be even more vulnerable, since it might have on-disk files that it's keeping open. Or just create a lot of sessions to see if the system gets slower, since it might be that looking for the right session file (when there are thousands) takes longer if sorting isn't implemented properly (full table scan is O(n), fat32 file listing is O(n)... people run all sorts of crazy setups).
- Analyzing the randomness of session tokens by generating tens of thousands of them.

Neither makes any sense in case of JWT, though, since they're signed instead of randomly generated. The whole point is that there is no server-side state, so there can't be too many files. Unless you have refresh tokens, because in that case you still have server-side state which one might attempt to DoS.

There are three more options I know of:

- Account sharing schemes may also do this. One example is Google Play Store accounts, where some open source front-ends will fetch login sessions from a server (so the server has the password and logs in to create a session). These login sessions are then sent to the people running this open source client, and they can use the Play Store, but it does not give them administrative account access (since you need the account password for that). This allows people to share an account and download APK file anonymously without trusting each other.

  It seems unlikely that this is the case since, if you run such a service where you snoop on everyone and people are trying to circumvent your snooping, you would probably already have realized that this is the reason.
- A poorly made bot may do this. If it wants to check the status of something, or perform some action, it might just log in every time (instead of reusing an old session) to avoid having to manage which session is currently active. If the owner sets it to run very frequently, you may get thousands of logins.
- In a less extreme case, you may also see a relatively high number of logins from "new devices" from humans. Not thousands, but perhaps a few dozen per day.

  I did this with stackoverflow until they implemented https, because I didn't want my cookie to leak over http. I would login and logout on networks that I trusted, so that if someone injects a stackoverflow request in an http page on an insecure network, my browser would not send a cookie where I am logged in.

  Nowadays I still do this with something like Twitter, where I don't want them to track me around the web, so I remove their cookies (automatically, using an add-on) and just briefly login (using my password manager, takes no time at all) when I want to do something such as liking a tweet.

Your system should not slow down from having too many sessions. Otherwise, it will also slow down (or crash) when you have a lot of legitimate users active at the same time. So the solution to malicious behaviour is obviously by making sure your system can handle it: make sure your lookups are [*O(log n)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (such as by adding an index to the session ID column, if you use a database-based scheme), and that they have plenty of entropy if you use randomly-generated tokens (you should do that anyway). In case of JWT (without refresh tokens), neither of these apply.

If your system is very small-scale and you just can't handle that many concurrent users, you could check upon login if the user already has active sessions, and if there are more than 5 (or so), remove their least-recently-used session.